# Node.js not sending proper POST message

Tags: node.js

I've got such a code in node.js:

```
var requestData = JSON.stringify({ id : data['user_id'] });
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 80,
    path: '/mypath/index.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Content-Length': requestData.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(requestData); 
req.end();
```

and PHP code:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST;
    define('DS', '/');
    umask(000);
    file_put_contents(dirname( __FILE__ ).DS.'log.txt', json_encode($data), FILE_APPEND);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

quite simple... but after making node.js POST request - PHP is not obtaining any data. I've tried many other ways of making that POST message to PHP but nothing works for me. I mean, `$_POST` is **always** empty.

Tried also [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) nodejs library:

```
    request.post({
        uri : config.server.protocol + '://localhost/someurl/index.php',
        json : JSON.stringify({ id : data['user_id'] }),
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('returned BODY:', body);
        }
        def.resolve(function() {
            callback(error);
        });
    });
```

There should be really simple solution for my problem but I can't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_POST` array is only populated with HTML form POST submits. To emulate such a form submit, you need to:

- Set the request Content-Type header exactly to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Use the form encoding in the request body... I.E `key=value&key2=value2` with [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) where necessary.
- Calculate the Content-Length header's value exactly to the length of **bytes** that are being sent. You can only do this after having the fully encoded string, though byte conversion is not necessary in order to calculate the Content-Length since 1 character = 1 byte in urlencoded string.

However, with your current code (provided all you have is ASCII), you can also do this:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $error = json_last_error();
    if( $error !== JSON_ERROR_NONE ) {
        die( "Malformed JSON: " . $error );
    }

    define('DS', '/');
    umask(000);
    file_put_contents(dirname( __FILE__ ).DS.'log.txt', json_encode($data), FILE_APPEND);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```